# Fractions with primes in different number systems

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, fractions, number-systems

I noticed a pattern in fractions of 7: 
1/7 = 0.142857142857142857... 
2/7 = 0.285714... 
3/7 = 0.428571... 
... 
As you can see, they all share the same 6 different numbers in the same order, only the starting point changes (the larger the numerator, the larger the first number). 

Which numbers besides 7 in which base have this property as well?
I made a [chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlZnM.png), where you can see for some bases (numbers on the left) and some denominators (numbers on the top), if they satisfy this property. My example from beginning (1/7) is the only one for base 10. Notice, that it only works, if the denominator is a prime (but not in all number systems). 
How can I show that every and only primes have this property?

Comment: Cyclic number, number freak 1 to 200

Comment: Do you only allow primes smaller than $b$ , if you are in the base-$b$-system ? The condition is that the multiplicative order of the prime $p$ with respect to the base $b$ is $p-1$ In base $10$ this means that $ord_{10}(p)=p-1$. It is conjectured that for every base $b$ there are infinite many primes $p$ for which this condition holds.